Style sibling based on is checked
I have a dropdown created only with css with the use of the hidden input. Now I want to outline the dropdown when it is closed if at least one option has been selected.
This play shows the dropdown. I tried with the peer-has but didn't manage to make it work


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<main className="w-full max-w-xl mx-auto">
  <h1 className="text-3xl mt-12">Multi-Select Dropdown</h1>
  <div className="flex flex-col">
    <label class="relative"
      ><input type="checkbox" class="peer hidden" />
      <div class="inline-flex cursor-pointer rounded border px-5 py-2 after:ml-1 after:inline-flex after:items-center after:text-xs after:transition-transform after:content-['▼'] peer-checked:after:-rotate-180">Select one or more countries</div>
      <div class="pointer-events-none absolute z-10 max-h-60 w-full overflow-y-scroll border bg-red-300 opacity-0 transition-opacity peer-checked:pointer-events-auto peer-checked:opacity-100">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <label class="[&amp;:has(input:checked)]:bg-blue-200 flex cursor-pointer whitespace-nowrap px-2 py-1 transition-colors hover:bg-blue-100"><input type="checkbox" class="cursor-pointer" name="countries2" value="Spain" /><span class="ml-1">Spain</span></label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label class="[&amp;:has(input:checked)]:bg-blue-200 flex cursor-pointer whitespace-nowrap px-2 py-1 transition-colors hover:bg-blue-100"><input type="checkbox" class="cursor-pointer" name="countries2" value="France" /><span class="ml-1">France</span></label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div></label
    >
  </div>
</main>




Please also included the code in your question as well. Posting debugging question with only an external link to code at here isn't enough as the link may be die in the future. It is also easier for people to look at the problem without having to open another website.

You could use a has-* arbitrary variant like has-[+*_:checked]:outline.
This checks the next sibling with :has(+*), and then checks if there are any :checked elements inside that sibling with * :checked.


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<main class="w-full max-w-xl mx-auto">
  <h1 class="text-3xl mt-12">Multi-Select Dropdown</h1>
  <div class="flex flex-col">
    <label class="relative"
      ><input type="checkbox" class="peer hidden" />
      <div class="inline-flex cursor-pointer rounded border px-5 py-2 after:ml-1 after:inline-flex after:items-center after:text-xs after:transition-transform after:content-['▼'] peer-checked:after:-rotate-180 has-[+*_:checked]:outline outline-2 outline-green-500">Select one or more countries</div>
      <div class="pointer-events-none absolute z-10 max-h-60 w-full overflow-y-scroll border bg-red-300 opacity-0 transition-opacity peer-checked:pointer-events-auto peer-checked:opacity-100">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <label class="[&:has(input:checked)]:bg-blue-200 flex cursor-pointer whitespace-nowrap px-2 py-1 transition-colors hover:bg-blue-100"><input type="checkbox" class="cursor-pointer" name="countries2" value="Spain" /><span class="ml-1">Spain</span></label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label class="[&:has(input:checked)]:bg-blue-200 flex cursor-pointer whitespace-nowrap px-2 py-1 transition-colors hover:bg-blue-100"><input type="checkbox" class="cursor-pointer" name="countries2" value="France" /><span class="ml-1">France</span></label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div></label
    >
  </div>
</main>



